# Kali Linux update-alternatives --config java

Tags: java

I am attempting to use L3MON to build an apk. It requires me to select Java 1.80 OpenJDK as I am currently running, however when I use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` it does not supply me with the option to select 1.80. See below.

I have installed Java 8 OpenJDK and it reflects in my `/usr/lib/jvm` file structure. I just can't seem to get the option to select it to use for L3MON.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *However when I use update-alternatives --config java , it does not supply me with the option to select 1.80* That would be for one of two reasons: a. it's not installed or b. it IS installed but was not installed with the package manager. My guess: it's the latter. If so, uninstall it and reinstall openjdk-8-jdk with the package manager

Answer (score 0):

To switch between installed JDKs:

1. List Java alternatives:

   ```
   update-java-alternatives -l
   ```
2. Find the line with the Java version that you want to select.
3. The output of `update-java-alternatives -l` will look something like this if Java 8 was installed by `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` which also matches the 2nd screenshot in your question.

   ```
   java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
   java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
   ```

   The first part of the second line there is `java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64`.
4. Set the first part of the line you want as the Java alternative.

   ```
   sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
   ```

To sum it all up the key thing to watch for here is that you have installed both of the Java versions that you want to switch between with apt so that both Java versions will be recognized.